# how to use Postman to Insert Document in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

What i need

- i need to Insert Test document.
- i have followed link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_index_and_query_a_document.html

Here im trying

```
   PUT /customer/_doc/1?pretty
  {
   "name": "John Doe"
  }
```

> Error request body is required

snapshot when i try to run url

1.http://localhost:9200/customer?pretty

[image]
2.http://localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty&pretty
[image]

3.http://localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty&pretty&name=test
[image]

can anyone suggest how to Insert document in Elastic search.

- any suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: What do you have in the `Body` request tab?

Comment: can you please tell how can in insert document through postman.

Comment: You need to insert the JSON document inside the request Body and make sure to specify the `Content-Type` request header with the `application/json` value.

Answer (score 4):

Pass the Json in body and change the URL as shown below:

[image: Put into elastic via postman]

Answer (score 3):

Use the PUT method for the same.

The url would be `"http://localhost:9200/movies/"`

movies is the name of the index.

The json to post is :

```
{
"id" : 1,
"title" : "Toy Story 1",
"year" : 1995,
"category" : "Adventure"
}
```

Here is the screenshot of the postman pushing the data to elasticseach :

[image: Postman1]

You can verify the data as below :

Use the GET method and the url as `http://localhost:9200/movies/_search?`

[image: Postman2]

Comment: Question please,
How to insert more(>10000) documents?

Comment: @L.Kvri, you can write a scheduler or batch job for processing this.

Comment: How can I do that in postman?
I dried to use /_bulk, but it not clear for me how to parametrize it in the body